# label for external luks disk by terminal

Tags: 16.04, mount, xubuntu, luks

I created a encrypted luks filesystem on an external disk. I used `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 LABELNAME` to set a label for the disk. But it is not used. I had to open the gui tool `Disks` to set the label again.

How I can do this working with terminal commands?

using xubuntu 16.04